# JPA ManyToMany relationship in Oracle NoSql - @JoinTable

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink, oracle-nosql, nosql

I am using JPA (eclipselink) to map two entities in Oracle NoSql DB having Many-to-Many relationship between them, what annotation do i use instead of @JoinTable annotation which is used in any relational db,

```
@JoinTable(name = "person_address", joinColumns =
{
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
}, inverseJoinColumns =
{
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressId")
})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

I was able to map One-to-Many relationship by using @JoinField annotation (in Oracle NoSql) instead of @JoinColumn annotation used in relational DB.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why did You expect typical relational behaviour on non-relational backend? Agree, Eclipselink has a layer over NoSQL but with many limitations, read docs.

Comment: @JacekCz I need to port mysql db to oracle nosql, on certain existing table we have such requirements.